# Current working directory no longer inherited from calling process from python 2.5 onwards?

Tags: python, import

I updated my python version on windows 2003 server from 2.4 to 2.5.

In 2.4 I could import a file "sub1.py" from a subdirectory c:\application\subdir\ like this:

```
import sub1
```

as long as the calling script main.py that lives in c:\application was started like this:

```
c:\application\subdir>python ..\main.py
```

But in 2.5 it no longer works for me:

```
C:\application\subdir>python ..\main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sub1
ImportError: No module named sub1
```

Now I can put an empty file

```
__init__.py
```

into subdir and import like this:

```
import subdir.sub1 as sub1
```

Was there a change in python 2.5? This would mean the current working directory in python 2.4 was inherited from the calling process, and in python 2.5 it is set to where the main script lives.

[edit3]
I corrected the question now. I must appologize that I had over-simplified the example at first and removed the cause that results in the error without checking my simplified example.
[/edit3]

Comment: Please keep the question and just say, that you found the problem and what it was... Downvotes for text like "sorry I removed the question" are ok!

Comment: you are smart but the downvote was before i changed it. that was the reason i removed it to NOT get more downvotes (because the nic downvoter did not even bother to comment why she or he did this. it is self protection)

Comment: Yeah, but to remove the question is still not the right way! I understand that this is not right if they downvote a correct question. It would be easier if you just let it be... everyone get some downvotes for no reason.

Comment: I rolled it back to the original - I'm not too sure what is going on here but I can't see why you would want to make your question into that "thanks for downvoting" thing - that is guaranteed to attract more downvotes. If you didn't like it that much, you can delete it I guess

Comment: i did not know about the deleting option, i will have a look. will deleting also delete my downvotes? please understand there must be some defence for anonymous downvoting with no reason. i think this is a bad thing here in SA. people put energy intoquestions and answers and downvoting should always be explained

Comment: Anonymous voting means that revenge voting cannot occur. I suggest you don't worry about it, downvoting doesn't have much of an effect on your reputation. For this post, if you got 2 downvotes, you also got 4 upvotes, this means you got a net result of +36 reputation. Upvotes have a more positive effect than down votes.

I don't know what effect deleting will have on your score or the downvotes, you could ask the team@stackoverflow.com or check the FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the following changes:

- turn `subdir` into a package by adding an empty `__init__.py` file to the directory
- change the import to: `from subdir import sub1`

Answer (score 4):

to import sub.py you need to:

```
import sub      # not sub1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check where python searches for modules. A list of locations is contained in variable sys.path.

You can create a simple script (or execute it interactively) that shows this:

```
import sys

for x in sys.path:
  print x
```

By default, python will search the directory in which it is being executed and where the original script resides.

Also, try setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable to include ".\" directory.

Comment: to find out i would have to install 2.4 again and then 2.5 again. i was hoping someone knows about a change from 2.4 to 2.5

Comment: You can check that on your 2.5 installation. You should be able to import it. Otherwise, you can do a simple test: create a file a.py with contents def foo(): print foo and then run python interactively from the directory this is in and type:  import a
then a.foo()
and you should get a print out. Also, you can run python in verbose mode and you will get more information: python -v backups.py. Just to be on the safe side, delete compiled versions (*.pyc)

Answer (score 1):

I assume `sub1` is a typo? In your question you sometimes refer to `sub`, sometimes to `sub1`.

I would first of all check that the sub.py file exists in `c:\application`.

- Check the permissions of the sub.py file and the application directory. Can the user read the sub.py file? Can the python interpreter create the *.pyc file?
- Also, manually delete the sub.pyc file, just in case an old version of the pyc is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add this directory to your python path

Comment: i thought i can import from the current working directory without it being on the path